# how can I change the css of a selected <Option/> of <Select/>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using React.js, and ant-design components.

I have a `<Select/>` component with a few `<Option/>` inside of it, now I know that on each selected option has this automatic hue added to it, but I want to change it do a different one, and also to change the background etc, but only if an option has been selected.

is there a way to do that?

(Select, Option Components - https://ant.design/components/select/ )

Comment: native html select or web framework? i'm sure there's a way to distinguish whether an option is selected, so you could use dynamic className to change a selected option's style

Comment: @fengxh as I wrote in the description, I am using React.js framework and ant-design components, so no native html select, and I am sure there is a way to distinguish whether the option is selected too, but I don't know the actual way, which is why I am asking here. if a dynamic className change behavior is possible I would love to hear about it - that is my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all sorry for my bad english, i dont know it is the best answer but when i want to change an element style i use its class and give that class a css. for selectbox you can use ant-select-selector in your css file :

```
.ant-select-selector{background-color:green}
```

if you want to check class for diffrent things you can check the element in dev tools.If you look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7oZu.png) img when i select to selectbox div i can see its own class and i can change its background-color.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
  <option selected="">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<style>
  option[selected]{
    background: #f00;
  }
</style>
```

This is the right CSS for this but I think it doesn't work on every browser. Even on Firefox it works only if you hover over the expanded options. Changing CSS styles of inputs was always pretty bad and weird. That's why there are libraries for that.

Comment: thanks but I am actually using a framework for that - React.js , and a library for the components - 'ant design', and I am looking at for a more general-always-working solution, and this isn't working at all in React.js..

Comment: You can find CSS for that: .ant-select-item-option-selected:not(.ant-select-item-option-disabled) { background: #f00 !important;}
All your selected "options" (because it is not real select/option tag) will be red.